# Why won't this work in both IE and Chrome. The Table only seems to be appearing correctly in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, html

So I have some code I'm trying in chrome when I found out I also need it to function in internet explorer...could someone please guide me on how to get this to fully function over in IE?

I know that it may have to have it's own code which I'd make functional...if I knew why IE was formatting the table incorrectly and not placing a row for each 7

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script>
    function calendar(month) {

        //Variables to be used later.  Place holders right now.
        var padding = "";
        var totalFeb = "";
        var i = 1;
        var testing = "";

        var current = new Date();
        var cmonth = current.getMonth(); // current (today) month
        var day = current.getDate();
        var year = current.getFullYear();
        var tempMonth = month + 1; //+1; //Used to match up the current month with the correct start date.
        var prevMonth = month - 1;

        //Determing if Feb has 28 or 29 days in it.  
        if (month == 1) {
            if ((year % 100 !== 0) && (year % 4 === 0) || (year % 400 === 0)) {
                totalFeb = 29;
            } else {
                totalFeb = 28;
            }
        }

        // Setting up arrays for the name of the months, days, and the number of days in the month.
        var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
        var dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thrusday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
        var totalDays = ["31", "" + totalFeb + "", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31"];

        // Temp values to get the number of days in current month, and previous month. Also getting the day of the week.
        var tempDate = new Date(tempMonth + ' 1 ,' + year);
        var tempweekday = tempDate.getDay();
        var tempweekday2 = tempweekday;
        var dayAmount = totalDays[month];

        // After getting the first day of the week for the month, padding the other days for that week with the previous months days.  IE, if the first day of the week is on a Thursday, then this fills in Sun - Wed with the last months dates, counting down from the last day on Wed, until Sunday.
        while (tempweekday > 0) {
            padding += "<td class='premonth'></td>";
            //preAmount++;
            tempweekday--;
        }
        // Filling in the calendar with the current month days in the correct location along.
        while (i <= dayAmount) {

            // Determining when to start a new row
            if (tempweekday2 > 6) {
                tempweekday2 = 0;
                padding += "</tr><tr>";
            }

            // checking to see if i is equal to the current day, if so then we are making the color of that cell a different color using CSS. Also adding a rollover effect to highlight the day the user rolls over. This loop creates the actual calendar that is displayed.
            if (i == day && month == cmonth) {
                padding += "<td class='currentday("+ i + ")'   onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#00AA00\"; this.style.color=\"#FFFFFF\"' onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"aqua\"; this.style.color=\"black\"'>" + i + "</td>";
            } else {
                padding += "<td id='currentmonth("+ i +")' class='currentmonth' onclick='DaySelection(" + i + ");' onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#00FF00\"' onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#FFFFFF\"'>" + i + "</td>";
            }
            tempweekday2++;
            i++;
        }


        // Outputing the calendar onto the site.  Also, putting in the month name and days of the week.
        var calendarTable = "<table class='calendar'> <tr class='currentmonth'><th colspan='7'>" + monthNames[month] + " " + year + "</th></tr>";
        calendarTable += "<tr class='weekdays'>  <td>Sun</td>  <td>Mon</td> <td>Tues</td> <td>Wed</td> <td>Thurs</td> <td>Fri</td> <td>Sat</td> </tr>";
        calendarTable += "<tr>";
        calendarTable += padding;
        calendarTable += "</tr></table>";
        document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML += calendarTable;
    }

    function go12() {
        var my_date = new Date();
        alert(my_date.getMonth());
        var MonthOFYear = my_date.getMonth();
        calendar(MonthOFYear);

    }

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', go12, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload', go12);
    }

    function DaySelection(a) {
        var selection = document.getElementById('currentmonth(' + a + ')').textContent;
        alert(selection);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`var tempDate = new Date(tempMonth + ' 1 ,' + year)`

This is the problematic line, since in IE 11 this is not a valid date. Because of this later in your for loop

```
 if (tempweekday2 > 6) {
     tempweekday2 = 0;
     padding += "</tr><tr>";
 }
```

tempweekday2 is not a number, so it will never enter the if statement, thus a new row will never be created.

To avoid this, you should always format your code according RFC 2822 or ISO 8601 so you can avoid these errors.

In your exact case, you can solve the problem by replacing

```
var tempDate = new Date(tempMonth + ' 1 ,' + year)
```

with :

```
var tempDate = new Date(tempMonth + '-1-' + year)
```